# in laravel is it possible to use cropit with ajax when i have two blade templates and both use ajax and cropit to read and save the image

Tags: ajax, laravel, laravel-5, cropit

in laravel i have two blade templates, and i read and show them using ajax in two bootstrap modals , i have cropit.js to crop images and save them one for edit user and one for insert user , however , i can not enclude both of my templates , one is overriding the other , for example when `@include('addstudent.blade.template')` is first , i can save the image using that , but i can't save the image with `@include('editstudent.blade.template')`  i even changed the name of the forms , but no success ! i can only include one of my blade templates , is there any solution so i can use them both ? ( remember i'm using ajax ) . here is the code for addstudent : from `$('#cropitbaby').on('submit',function (e)` to `e.preventDefault();` , is the important part , the rest is not relevant to my question .

```
    $('#frm-insert').on('submit',function (e) {

        $('#cropitbaby').on('submit',function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
        });
        $('#cropitbaby').submit();
        var passdata = $("input#image-data").val();
        $("input#usercropedimage").val(passdata);
        var data = $(this).serialize();
        var url = $(this).attr('action');
        var post = $(this).attr('method');
        e.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            type:post,
            url:url,
            data:data,
            dataty:'json',
            success:function (data) {
                var tr = $('<tr/>',{
                    id : data.id
                });
                tr.append($('<td/>',{
                    text:data.id
                })).append($('<td/>',{
                    text:data.cell_phone
                })).append($('<td/>',{
                    text:data.email
                })).append($('<td/>',{
                    text:data.created_at_shamsi
                })).append($('<td/>',{
                    text:data.gender
                })).append($('<td/>',{
                    text:data.username
                })).append($('<td/>',{
                    text:data.family
                })).append($('<td/>',{
                    text:data.name
                })).append($('<td/>',{


                    html : '<a href="#" class="btn btn-info btn-sm" id="view" data-id="' + data.id + '">تغییر رمز</a> '
                    + '<a href="#" class="btn btn-success btn-sm" id="edit" data-id="' + data.id + '">ویرایش</a> ' +
                    '<a href="#" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" id="del" data-id="' + data.id + '">حذف</a>'
                }));


                $("input#image-data").cropit('destroy');
                $('#student-info').append(tr);
            }
        })
    })
```

the code for update is the same . but that is not the problem . the problem is why one of them is overriding another , for example if i use and include `addstudent.blade.php` i would not be able to use update ( i mean the part that relates to reading and saving the image with cropit ) . it would get its data from `addstudent.blade.php` !!

Comment: I don't think this question is appealing to anyone willing to help. Try being more concise or making it more readable.

Comment: please share the blade code as well here for both templates

Comment: you want to see the blade :))) . do you even understood what i said about my problem ?